# NumberFormatException in thread?

Tags: java, networking, network-programming

Need some more help. Working on network chat programming from the cherno's tutorial series. I got to 24 and thats when things started going bad. I launched the server, I connected to it with a local client and connected to localhost, all that working fine. When I connect I get this error.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "8474"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at com.josh.chat.ClientWindow$1.run(ClientWindow.java:78)
```

I set a random 4 digit number and I assign it as the ID here, and this is where the error applies to:

```
    public void listen() {
    listen =  new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while(running) {                
                String message = client.receive();
                if(message.startsWith("/c/")) {
                    message.trim();
                    client.setID(Integer.parseInt(message.split("/c/|/e/")[1]));
                    console("Successfully connected to server! ID: " + client.getID());
                }
            }               
        }

    };
    listen.start();
}
```

EDIT: added the whole function

The /c/ and /e/ SHOULD be working fine, I see no problems with them.

Comment: What is the value of the message string?

Comment: This is not the issue of networking, to clear things out. your function is trying to convert 8474 but unable to do so because of the exception. Can you explain what do you intend to do with message.split("/c/|/e/")[1]?

Comment: Yes Muneeb, everytime the server or the client sends a message it starts with /[something]/ and ends with /e/ /e/ goes directly after the string, so there should be no blank spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If the String is really "8474", the exception can't happen. So I would say the String is not actually "8474". Maybe there is some encoding problem and any hidden character you don't see?

Try:

```
String whatever = message.split("/c/|/e/")[1]).trim();
byte[] bytes = whatever.getBytes();
String str = new String(bytes, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
System.out.println(str); // control before trying to parse ...
client.setID(Integer.parseInt(str);
```